# Luxon DateTime's format showing "am", "pm" instead of "AM", "PM"

Tags: datetime, luxon

I have following code using Luxons' DateTime to format a datetime:

```
const cur = DateTime.fromISO("2022-06-22T06:49:07.911Z").toFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a");
```

Luxon returns:

```
"06/22/2022 02:49 AM"
```

I prefer to have following output (small **am**):

```
"06/22/2022 02:49 am"
```

Can Loxon do that? Or I need to lowercase the return value?
(I'm focusing on Luxon only, no other library needed, please ;-)

Comment: You don't need Luxon for that `"06/22/2022 02:49 AM".toLowerCase()`

Comment: Luxon uses the Intl API to generate that string. And that API has decided that it's called "AM". You can toLowerCase() it, but note this might a bad idea in other locales.